# Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of reals going to $0$ but whose series diverges. Prove that we can flip the signs of each term to get a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers that converges to $0$ but whose series diverges. Show that for amy real number $r$ there is a sequence $\sigma_n$, consisting of $1$ and $-1$'s, such that
$$\sum_n \sigma_n a_n = r$$.

I am confused about how to show this. Considering the partial sums, we can construct a sequence of partial sums such that the sum of first few terms (by making all of them positive) go just above $r$, and make the 'second' frw terms all negative so that the partial sums up to that point goes just below $r$, and continue the process. But I wasn't sure how to make this mathematically rigorous.

Comment: This has already been asked. Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148663/if-a-n-goes-to-zero-can-we-find-signs-s-n-such-that-sum-s-n-a-n-converge

Comment: @FranciscoMaion This is not a duplicate. We are given a real sequence $a_n$ here. The complex case is much more difficult

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You're on the right track. We just need to choose these subsums carefully.

Let $N_1$ be the smallest integer such that $\sum_{n=1}^{N_1}|a_n| > r.$ Then let $N_2$ be the smallest integer such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N_1}|a_n| - \sum_{n=N_1 + 1}^{N_2}|a_n| < r.$$

Continue ... Call these sums $S_1, S_2, \dots.$ The "smallest" criterion in choosing the $N_k,$ together with the fact that $a_n\to 0,$ guarantees that $S_1-S_2 + S_3 - \cdots = r.$

Comment: Thanks, but could you please show that it approaches $r$ more rigorously, using the epsilon delta argument?