# Prove: Given the harmonic sequence, One can add '+' and '-' signs such that the resulting series sum will be zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to prove the following:

1. Given the harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^∞ 1/n$, One can add '+' and '-' Signs such that the sum of the resulting series will be zero.
2. Will this remain true for any $\sum_{n=1}^∞ a_n$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n = 0$?

To be honest, It doesn't feel so intuitive to me.
I guess that If I knew how to add the '+' and '-' signs, All I need to do is to prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_n = 0$, Wheres $S_n$ Is the partial sum of the resulting series.

Ive tried to look at this:
[changing the signs of the harmonic series so that it converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600519/changing-the-signs-of-the-harmonic-series-so-that-it-converges)

And this: [If $a_n$ goes to zero, can we find signs $s_n$ such that $\sum s_n a_n$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148663/if-a-n-goes-to-zero-can-we-find-signs-s-n-such-that-sum-s-n-a-n-converge?rq=1)

But did not help much.

Comment: This remains true as long as the positive summands form a monotone sequence tending to $0$. Just add summands until you arrrive at a positive number, subtract summands until you arrive at a negative number and so on. This way, you can even let the sum tend to any real number you want.

Comment: Of course the sum $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots$ must diverge